# How to get the buttons current enabled/disabled status in WPF multibind 'Convert' method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My program has this kind of a multi bind

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
<Binding Path="SelectedItems.Count"/>
<Binding Path="EffectiveStyleContext.Selection"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

IS there anyway to get the current enable disable status in the `Convert` method

```
class myConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //I need to get current status here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass control itself into a `ValueConverter`.

Your modified `Xaml` will be

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
    <Binding Path="SelectedItems.Count"/>
    <Binding Path="EffectiveStyleContext.Selection"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Now in your coverter code you will be able to access control.

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{  
    public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var control = values[0] as FrameworkElement;
        var value1 = values[1] as int;

        // write your logic here.          
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, System.Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return throw new System.NotImplementedException();;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why can't converterParameter be used for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind direct to the property itself:

```
<Binding Path="IsEnabled" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
```

I would actually argue that this is preferable because the MultiBinding won't get updated when the enable state changes otherwise.